# Scrapy - xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping restaurant reviews from yelp, specifically from this [url](https://www.yelp.it/biz/roscioli-roma-4?rr=4)

I'm trying to get the list of review containers and, after testing with the chrome console, that would be given by the following xpath expression:

`//li/div[@class='css-1qn0b6x']`

However, by testing with scrapy shell, the following command returns an empty list

`response.xpath("//li/div[@class='css-1qn0b6x']").extract()`

Comment: The reviews are loaded in dynamically after the main page loads, they can be seen at these endpoints: https://www.yelp.it/biz/MtnKUDm2a9PckD_qnEAE5w/review_feed?rr=4  
https://www.yelp.it/biz/MtnKUDm2a9PckD_qnEAE5w/review_feed?rr=4&rl=it&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start=10

Comment: Where can I locate this url on the page? I need it because I would reach this page from another page containing a restaurant list. In order to scrape all this json file I need to be able to tell the scraper where to get them.

Comment: the id used in the api url (MtnKUDm2a9PckD_qnEAE5w) is within the HTML of the original url you posted, see my answer where I give an example of some code that gathers reviews after first getting that id from the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments above, see an example of how you can gather reviews by first getting the `yelp-biz-id` from the HTML of the original page you linked:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()

url = 'https://www.yelp.it/biz/roscioli-roma-4'
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

resp = s.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')
biz_id = soup.find('meta',{'name':'yelp-biz-id'})['content']

reviews = []
for page in range(5):

    api_url = f'https://www.yelp.it/biz/{biz_id}/review_feed?start={page*10}'
    resp  = s.get(api_url,headers=headers)
    
    data = resp.json()
    reviews = data['reviews']

    if resp.status_code == 200 and len(reviews) > 0:

        df = pd.json_normalize(reviews)
        reviews.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(reviews).reset_index()
final_df
```